# How to get RecipientTypeDetails through the MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to get the `RecipientTypeDetails` property of a mailbox through any (Graph) REST API? From my research I've been seeing No's as answers, but I didn't find any recent confirmation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A -1 without an explanation what's missing in a question can only be worse and less helpful than the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I use exchange-online-powershell to get RecipientTypeDetails to retrieve all the mailboxes of a recipient type. I couple this with MS Graph. However, I couldn't retrieve the mailboxes of a certain type using MS graph.

So you can do something like this in powershell.

```
$recipientTypes = Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited
```

Then use it to retrieve mailboxes of a type and output to file. Unsure how you want to use it.

```
foreach($recType in $recipientTypes)
{
    $mailboxes = (Get-Mailbox -Filter '(RecipientTypeDetails -eq $($recType))')
    ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $mailboxes | Out-File ".\Mailboxes-$($recType).json"
}
```

The module I use is:

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.4-Preview2 -AllowPrerelease`
```

Comment: This might be the best answer, as in not supported but this way you can generate JSON files for later processing

Comment: Generally, this is a good answer, but still not the (pure) Graph API solution I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be something exposed for Exchange on premises via a powershell cmlet named [Get-Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-recipient?view=exchange-ps). It is not exposed via Graph Rest Apis after inspecting the docs and playing around with graph explorer. The user object doesn't have a mailbox property, it has a messages collection.

In the docs there is guidance indicating that for cloud environments you can invoke the cmdlet with the RecipientTypeDetails set to GroupMailBox.